# Define visit methods to use only in an ast.While object

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I try to write a [pylint plugin](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/how_tos/plugins.html)
(a checker) and the object I want check is `ast.While`,
especially the body. I am interested in the operations done
on the variables of the test Comparison (I work only with `ast.While`
which the test expression is a `ast.Compare` object). So, the
interesing cases are `ast.AugAssign` or `ast.Assign` or taking
a slice from a subscriptable if the objects in the comparison
are `int`, ...

I defined the methods for `ast.Name`, `ast.Attribute`, ... to extract
the variable name. But the issue is that I want this behaviour
only in a `ast.While` body, because I have attributes in my class
(`TestWhile(ast.NodeVisitor)`) that stores information so I do not
want them to be modified outside a `ast.While` body.
Should I define, for example, `visit_Name()` in the definition
of the `visit_While` method ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by creating two visitor classes.  One would be responsible for identifying `ast.While` nodes, the other for visiting the nodes *inside* the while node.

```
class WhileVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_While(self, node):
        body_visitor = BodyVisitor()
        body_visitor.visit(node)
        return


class BodyVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        # do stuff

    # define methods to visit any other nodes of interest.
```

By separating responsibility for identify while nodes and processing their bodies you can be be sure that only nodes within while nodes will be processed.

Comment: I thought about that and did something similar. Is it possible to do something like that using `astroid` ? I do not found any class in `astroid` that only visits the tree like `ast.NodeVisitor` does.